# How to code modal popup with edit feature in asp.net calendar control C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, calendar, popup, modal-dialog

I have been stuck for days and searching everything but not sure how to apply my code to do the following.
I have a calendar using the asp.net calendar control. 
I need to be able to click on a already existing event in the calendar and have a popup appear that shows me the detail of the event.

These details are taken from the existing database ("Events") and display in the modal popup.
The popup includes an edit and delete feature which would update the database and calendar on click.

Can anyone Help me with this???

Some far I have coded the calendar (which has textboxes below it) to take the event inserted in the textboxes and put the event title into the calendar day cell with a bckground color. It also updates the database with the event information.

I am just missing this modal popup piece.

Below is my existing C# code:
    `using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.UI;
    using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Configuration;
    using System.Net.Mail;

```
namespace Calender
{
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    SqlConnection con = new 
  SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].
  ConnectionString);

    protected DataSet dsMonth;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con.Open();

        //if (!IsPostBack)
       // {


            Calendar1.VisibleDate = DateTime.Today;
            FillEventDataset();

       // }
    }


    protected void FillEventDataset()
    {
        DateTime firstDate = new DateTime(Calendar1.VisibleDate.Year,
            Calendar1.VisibleDate.Month, 1);
        DateTime lastDate = GetFirstDayOfNextMonth();
        dsMonth = GetCurrentMonthData(firstDate, lastDate);
    }

    protected DateTime GetFirstDayOfNextMonth()
    {
        int monthNumber, yearNumber;
        if (Calendar1.VisibleDate.Month == 12)
        {
            monthNumber = 1;
            yearNumber = Calendar1.VisibleDate.Year + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            monthNumber = Calendar1.VisibleDate.Month + 1;
            yearNumber = Calendar1.VisibleDate.Year;
        }
        DateTime lastDate = new DateTime(yearNumber, monthNumber, 1);
        return lastDate;
    }

    protected DataSet GetCurrentMonthData(DateTime firstDate,
         DateTime lastDate)
    {
        DataSet dsMonth = new DataSet();
        ConnectionStringSettings cs;
        cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"];
        String connString = cs.ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection dbConnection = new SqlConnection(connString);

        String query;
        query = "SELECT Date, Evnt FROM Events " +
            " WHERE Date >= @firstDate AND Date < @lastDate";
        SqlCommand dbCommand = new SqlCommand(query, dbConnection);
        dbCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@firstDate",
            firstDate));
        dbCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@lastDate", lastDate));

        SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(dbCommand);
        try
        {
            sqlDataAdapter.Fill(dsMonth);
        }
        catch { }
        return dsMonth;
    }


    protected void Calendar1_DayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
    {

        DateTime nextDate;

        if (dsMonth != null)
        {
            foreach (DataRow dr in dsMonth.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                nextDate = (DateTime)dr["Date"];

                if (nextDate == e.Day.Date) 
                {
                    e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Pink;

                    Label lb = new Label();
                   lb.Visible = true;
                   lb.Text = "<br/>";
                   lb.Text += dr[1].ToString();
                   string a = lb.Text;
                   e.Cell.Controls.Add(lb);
                   lb.ToolTip = dr[1].ToString(); // tooltip display in day 
                   e.Cell.Controls.Add(lb);


                }
            }   
          }
        }

    protected void Calendar1_VisibleMonthChanged(object sender,
    MonthChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        FillEventDataset();
    }

    protected void Calendar1_SelectionChanged1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        TxtBxDate.Text = Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy"); 
    //Selected date is displayed in the date text box
    }

    protected void BtnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // Clearing 
    out all textboxes
    {
        TxtBxDate.Text = "";
        TxtBxEvnt.Text = "";
        TxtBoxDescrption.Text = "";
        TxtBxContName.Text = "";
        EmailTxtBx.Text = "";
        TxtBxPhn.Text = "";
    }

    protected void BtnSbmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //mapping 
     textboxes to the matching column in Event database
    {


        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Events" + "(Date, Evnt, 
Descrption, ContName, Phn) values (@Date, @Evnt, @Descrption, @ContName, 
@Phn)", con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", TxtBxDate.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Evnt", TxtBxEvnt.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Descrption", TxtBoxDescrption.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContName", TxtBxContName.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", EmailTxtBx.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Phn", TxtBxPhn.Text);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close(); 
        TxtBxDate.Text = "";     //Clear out all text boxes on submit
        TxtBxEvnt.Text = "";
        TxtBoxDescrption.Text = "";
        TxtBxContName.Text = "";
        EmailTxtBx.Text = "";
        TxtBxPhn.Text = "";


    }

}

}
 **` ASP.net aspx.**
  <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" 
  CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" 
 Inherits="Calender.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<style type="text/css">
    .auto-style1 {
        width: 343px;
    }
    .auto-style2 {
        width: 339px;
    }
    .auto-style3 {
        width: 329px;
    }
    .auto-style4 {
        width: 339px;
        height: 42px;
    }
    .auto-style5 {
        width: 329px;
        height: 42px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>

    <asp:Calendar ID="Calendar1" runat="server" BackColor="White" 
BorderColor="White" BorderWidth="1px" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="9pt" 
ForeColor="Black" Height="380px" NextPrevFormat="FullMonth" Width="700px" 
OnSelectionChanged="Calendar1_SelectionChanged1" 
OnDayRender="Calendar1_DayRender" ToolTip="enable">
        <DayHeaderStyle Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="8pt" />
        <NextPrevStyle Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="8pt" ForeColor="#333333" 
VerticalAlign="Bottom" />
        <OtherMonthDayStyle ForeColor="#999999" />
        <SelectedDayStyle BackColor="#333399" ForeColor="White" />
        <TitleStyle BackColor="White" BorderColor="Black" BorderWidth="4px" 
Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="12pt" ForeColor="#333399" />
        <TodayDayStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
    </asp:Calendar>

</div><br />
    <div><br />

         <table class="auto-style1" id="InsertTable">
        <tr>
            <td class="auto-style4" id="lblSelectDate">Selected Date</td>
            <td class="auto-style5">
                <asp:TextBox ID="TxtBxDate" runat="server" Width="192px">
</asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="auto-style2" id="lblEvent">Event </td>
            <td class="auto-style3">
                <asp:TextBox ID="TxtBxEvnt" runat="server" Width="331px">
 </asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="auto-style2" id="lblDescrp">Description</td>
            <td class="auto-style3">
                <asp:TextBox ID="TxtBoxDescrption" runat="server" 
 TextMode="MultiLine" Width="331px"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="auto-style2" id="lblContName">Contact Name</td>
            <td class="auto-style3">
                <asp:TextBox ID="TxtBxContName" runat="server" 
 Width="332px"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
            <td class="auto-style2" id="lblPhne">Email</td>
            <td class="auto-style3">
                <asp:TextBox ID="EmailTxtBx" runat="server" Width="315px">
 </asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
            <td class="auto-style2" id="lblPhne">Phone</td>
            <td class="auto-style3">
                <asp:TextBox ID="TxtBxPhn" runat="server" Width="331px">
 </asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="auto-style2"><asp:Button ID="BtnCancel" 
 runat="server" Text="Clear" OnClick="BtnCancel_Click" /></td>
            <td class="auto-style3">

                <asp:Button ID="BtnSbmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" 
 OnClick="BtnSbmit_Click" />

            </td>
        </tr>
              <tr>
            <td></td>
                           <td>
                               <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" 
 runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 
 SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Events]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
                  </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```